# ¿Cómo obtener el numero de días de la semana, mes y año actual?

Tags: sql-server, date

Quiero realizar una **`consulta`**, la cual me cuente el numero de días de la semana actual, por ejemplo, supongamos que en esta semana se realizaron ventas y quiero sacar el **`promedio`** de ventas de esta semana, que sería del día **`30 de julio de 2018`** al día de hoy **`5 de agosto de 2018`**. O hasta el día que esté en curso, por ejemplo si hoy fuese **`2 de agosto de 2018`**, que me cuente desde el día que inició la semana **(`30 de julio de 2018`)** hasta el actual, para sacar el **`promedio`** de ventas que lleva en la fracción de la semana o en la semana entera o de acuerdo al numero de semana que el usuario quiera ver.

Y de igual forma quiero hacerlo para **`mes`** y **`año`**. Pero no he encontrado nada, razón por la cual no muestro algún ejemplo expresado en **`código`**, solo la explicación de lo que busco.

Comment: basta con un BETWEEN basado en dos fechas, ademas necesitas repasar un poco la documentación basado en fechas, de ahí te darías cuenta que de la fecha actual se le puede restar 7 días  para obtener la fecha de la semana anterior o bien mes o años.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer los siguientes cálculos

```
DECLARE @Fecha              DATETIME
DECLARE @FirstDayOfWeek     DATETIME
DECLARE @FirstDayOfMonth    DATETIME
DECLARE @FirstDayOfYear     DATETIME

SELECT  @Fecha      = '2018-08-05'

-- Nos aseguramos que el Lunes sea el primer día de la semana
SET DATEFIRST  1

SELECT @FirstDayOfWeek  = DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(dw, @Fecha)-1)*-1, @Fecha)
SELECT @FirstDayOfMonth = CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Fecha,112),6)+'01')
SELECT @FirstDayOfYear  = CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Fecha,112),4)+'0101')

SELECT  @FirstDayOfWeek         AS 'PrimerDiaSemana',
        @FirstDayOfMonth        AS 'PrimerDiaMes',
        @FirstDayOfYear         AS 'PrimerDiaAño'
```

- El primer día de la semana se calcula obteniendo el día de la semana actual le restamos 1 y esa cantidad de días se la restamos a la fecha inicial
- Para el mes y el año, no usamos ninguna aritmética y hacemos algo más básico, con la fecha como cadena nos quedamos con el año/mes y le agregamos un `01` para obtener el primer día del mes y `0101` con el `año` para el primer día del año.

Comment: Muy bien, el primer día del mes y del año funcionan correctamente, cambié los `datetime` por `date`, pero el del día de la semana me muestra esta fecha `2018-07-30` y no el día de hoy `2018-08-06`.

Comment: @valle50, has modificado la fecha? fijate que dice `SELECT  @Fecha      = '2018-08-05'`

Answer (score 2):

Si no lo he entendido mal necesitas el promedio de ventas de una semana/mes/ año.

Tengo esta sentencia en postgres. Supongo que podrás traducirla a sql-server y a ver si funciona.

```
SELECT Sum(total_ventas) / full_count
FROM   (SELECT Count(1) OVER()           AS full_count,
               fecha                     AS dia,
               count(ventas)               AS total_ventas
        FROM   table_ventas
        WHERE  fecha BETWEEN :fecha_start AND :fecha_end
        GROUP  fecha) subquery
GROUP  BY full_count
```

Explico, el subquery me va a dar el sumatorio de ventas por día y el numero de días que tengo entre las dos fechas que he puesto en el `where`.
Esto me lo tiene que agrupar por días ya que entiendo que puedan haber  de 0 a muchas ventas el mismo día.

Sabiendo el numero de ventas y el numero de días solamente tengo que dividirlo para saber el promedio que ha tenido en ese plazo de tiempo.

Ahora bien, Depende de como tengas planteada la tabla `ventas` tendrás que hacer modificaciones, pero el concepto es ese. Sacar el numero de días, el numero de ventas y dividirlo entre si para saber el promedio

Comment: No se que me da, que no he entendido del todo la pregunta :S

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte @Txema Alment, lo tomaré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede servir, prueba y me comentas:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @FECHA_INICIO, @FECHA_FIN) AS FLOAT)
FROM VENTAS
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
```